# How can I show only one taxonomy using custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type and inside the custom post I have a taxonomy named "instruments". Each post can have more than one "instrument".

But I just want to display one (or the first one) at the homepage. Like: "Instrument A, Instrument B, Instrument C. But only show Instrument A".

Right now I'm using this code.

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'instruments' );
           foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the first term from the taxonomy terms array

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'instruments' );
    $first_term = reset($terms);
    echo $first_term->name;
?>
```

If you are using > php 5.4, here's a one liner

```
echo reset($terms)->name;
```

The [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function "Set the internal pointer of an array to its first element". So you basically access the first term of the array.